# I received data normally with socket emit, but refetching is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, socket.io, frontend

I am using useState Hook to get setList values, users state values, and data values ​​from socket.on(users).

However, my problem is that I receive the data normally, but when the data changes on the server, the list state value should be refetched, but it is not being refetched.

How can I refetch the list value in useEffect to automatically render it when the data is updated on the server?

I put a list in useEffect deps out of curiosity, but re-rendering occurs by calling the list infinitely.

```
  const [list, setList] = useState<any>([]);

useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("connect", () => {
    });
 
    socket.on("users", (data: any) => {
      setList(data);
    });

    socket.emit(users);
    return () => {
      socket.off(users);
    };
  }, [socket]);
```